# Is this a KnockoutJS bug or am I doing multiple bindings wrong?

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I've been working my way through the KnockoutJS documentation and tried to modify example 3 of the "Writeable computed observables" section in this [page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).

The example basically shows a textbox and displays a message if the user enters a non-numeric value to the textbox. I tried to modify the code so that the textbox has a pink background when the message appears.

The problem is when you enter a invalid value the textbox turns pink as expected but the value you entered is replaced with what was originally there. I have no idea why this behavior is occurring since everything worked fine before I added the style binding to get the pink background. Try removing the style binding and notice how the behavior changes when you enter an invalid value.

What's going on?

The code is below or try out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMbH6/).

```
<p>
  Enter a numeric value:
  <input data-bind="value: attemptedValue
                   ,style: {backgroundColor: lastInputWasValid() ?
                                             'transparent' :
                                             'pink' }"/>
</p>
<div data-bind="visible: !lastInputWasValid()">That's not a number!</div>

function MyViewModel() {
  this.acceptedNumericValue = ko.observable(123);
  this.lastInputWasValid = ko.observable(true);

  this.attemptedValue = ko.computed({
      read: this.acceptedNumericValue,
      write: function (value) {
          if (isNaN(value))
              this.lastInputWasValid(false);   
          else {
              this.lastInputWasValid(true);
              this.acceptedNumericValue(value); // Write to underlying storage
          }
      },
      owner: this
  });   
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

EDIT: Here's another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JzJ8/) with the style binding removed. Try appending the letter 'a' and taking focus out of the textbox. Notice how the letter 'a' stays there. Try that with the original [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMbH6/) textbox and notice how it is removed. The only change between the two fiddles is the presence of the style binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I sent [an email to the KnockoutJS user group](http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/browse_thread/thread/7044671b52cf575) and got a reply in about 7 hours (not too shabby).

Sadly, Google Groups confuses me and I have no idea how to reply to the fellow who cleared up my question to tell him to come on over here and post his answer so I guess I'll do it for him. All credit goes to John Earles of the KO user group.

> It make sense to me.
>
> In your example without the style, Knockout does not have to re-render
>   your input (only the error), so the value stays the same.
>   In your example with the style, Knockout does have to re-render your
>   input (to add the style), so BOTH bindings execute and it reads the
>   value - which is the last accepted value.
>
> Here is a version that saves the attempted value into one of two
>   observables, and reads from the appropriate one based on
>   lastInputWasValid:
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/VSWfr/

Answer (score 1):

If the value is NAN than it is never written to the model, therefore the input will be updated to the existing value of the model when the `onblur` event is fired.

`this.acceptedNumericValue(value); // Write to underlying storage`

Is the code that updates when the value is numerical.  You can see that it is not in the `else` block.

Comment: Have you tried removing the style binding like I mentioned? Just by doing so, the behavior changes so that the invalid value is left on the textbox instead of being removed. Here's a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JzJ8/) with the style binding removed. Try appending in the letter 'a' and notice how it stays there. Try doing so with the original fiddle and notice the difference when you append the letter 'a' and leave the textbox.